# TypeError when trying to Proxy a ES6 class constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I'm trying to Proxy a ES6 constructor (mostly trying to emulate Python's descriptors for fun and learning):

```js
class _Record {
    constructor(data) {
        this._data = data;
    }
}

const constrProxyHandlers = {
    construct: function(target, args, cstr) {
        let instProxyHandler = {
            get: (target, prop) => {
                if(prop in target._data) { return target._data[prop] }
                return target[prop]
            },
            set: (target, prop, val) => {
                if(prop in target._data) {
                    target._data[prop] = val;
                } else {
                    target[prop] = val;
                }
                return true
            }
        }
        
        let obj = Object.create(cstr.prototype)
        cstr.apply(obj, args)
        return new Proxy(obj, instProxyHandler)
    }
}

const Record = new Proxy(_Record, constrProxyHandlers)

let rec = new Record({name: 'Vic', age: 25})
console.log([rec.name, rec.age])
rec.name = 'Viktor'
console.log(rec)
```

If you run this snippet, you'll get this error:

```
cstr.apply(obj, args)

TypeError: Class constructor _Record cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

If I replace `cstr.apply` with `new cstr`, the constructor quickly exhausts stack (apparently going into an infinite recursion).

This **works** if I replace the `_Record` class with a function (for example, this **would work** transpiled through Babel). Can I make it work with native ES6?

Thank you.

P. S. I'm currently checking these snippets on Node 7.7.4, if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part

```
let obj = Object.create(cstr.prototype)
cstr.apply(obj, args)
```

does not work with ES6 classes. You need to use

```
let obj = Reflect.construct(target, args, cstr);
```

(and not `Reflect.construct(cstr, args)` or `new cstr(...args)` that you were trying to do, which indeed recurses infinitely - IIRC `target` refers to `_Record` while `cstr` refers to `Record` or one of its subclasses).