# Proxy ES6 class and maintain prototype chain

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I'm proxying methods using the following wrapper:

```js
  public static wrap(target) {
    function construct(constructor, args) {
      const c: any = function(this) {
        return constructor.apply(this, args);
      };

      c.prototype = constructor.prototype;
      return new c();
    }

    const f = (...args) => {
      const instance = construct(target, args);

      const descriptors = getMethodDescriptors(target, instance);

      return new Proxy<T>(
        instance,
        new SomeProxyHandler(descriptors)
      );
    };

    f.prototype = target.prototype;
    return f;
  }
```

This has worked well when wrapping classes which are compiled down to ES5 but now I'm trying to target ES6 I'm getting errors at `constructor.apply(this, args)` saying that:

```
TypeError: Class constructor OneOfMyClasses cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

How can I fix this code so `wrap` can proxy classes whatever the JavaScript target and maintain the correct prototype chain?

Comment: related: [How to use a Proxy in javascript to capture a constructor while maintaining the prototype chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49738211/1048572) and [TypeError when trying to Proxy a ES6 class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43104420/1048572)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would be spread syntax

```
const instance = new target(...args);
```

but you can also use [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct):

```
const instance = Reflect.construct(target, args);
```

This will even be necessary if your wrapped classes are supposed to be extensible, you then will have to make use of [`new.target`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32450516/1048572):

```
const instance = Reflect.construct(target, args, new.target);
```

---

Btw, your `f` wrapper should be a [proper `function` not an arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572), as those cannot be called with `new` (and don't have `new.target`). Or maybe even simpler (working better with static methods and inheritance), just wrap the whole `target` class itself in a `Proxy` and use its [`construct` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/construct).